# Spark: stanford-nlp runs too slow in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In my application, I run nlp job with stanford NLP. The stanford parse model is packed in a jar, and rigisters as an UDF, I use sqlContext.sql to use it. But I feel it runs so slowly. Anyone can help me speed it up?

The codes as follows:

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION segmenter AS 'cn.com.datamesh.stanford.nlp.StanfordNlp'").collect()
sqlContext.sql("SELECT segmenter(text) FROM twitter_data")
```

Comment: Did you succeed in improving the speed in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the Stanford CoreNLP wrapper for Spark. It should simplify the usage and hopefully speed up your code. Here is the [git page](https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp) which also includes the commands avaiable. As shown in this [short installation guide](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1233855/3233914658600709/588180/latest.html) you can attach a language model to the Spark context directly using the following commands:

```
val version = "3.6.0"
val model = s"stanford-corenlp-$version-models" // append "-english" to use the full English model
val jars = sc.asInstanceOf[{def addedJars: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Long]}].addedJars.keys // use sc.listJars in Spark 2.0
if (!jars.exists(jar => jar.contains(model))) {
  import scala.sys.process._
  s"wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/$version/$model.jar -O /tmp/$model.jar".!!
  sc.addJar(s"/tmp/$model.jar")
}
```

For supported models you can see the CoreNLP website.